# Which distribution should I use

Tags: mathematical-statistics

Which distribution can have average which is equals to the 3rd percentile? Is that possible?

```
nd = NormalDistribution(mu=100, std=12)
p = nd.prob(98)
```

F.E.In normal average will equal to 50-th percentile. Could you please suggest such a distrubution?

Comment: A distribution degenerate at 0, would do: $P(X=0)=1.$ Then _all_ percentiles are at 0 along with the mean. // Definitions of percentiles differ slightly from one text or software package to another. Depending on your definition, you might keep almost all probability at 0, but put tiny (equal) bits of probability at $\pm 1$ to get a more interesting example.

Comment: Any variable whose negative has a lognormal distribution with geometric standard deviation $0.940397$ will do.  So will myriad other distributions.  So, then, could you explain the purpose of your inquiry?  If you intend to use such a distribution to model some phenomenon, then you will want to specify additional criteria.

Answer (score 3):

It's possible to get a mean equal to, or above, or below any percentile. Very skew distributions will tend to get means at extreme percentiles. As with the sample mean and 3rd percentile for this set of data (shown in the plot below):

```
> mean(a)
[1] 47.92832
> quantile(a1,p=.03)
      3% 
47.92832
```

[image: Plot of very left-skew data with mean equal to 3rd percentile]

Any number of distributions will have this property, and yet they may have very different *other* properties (different skewness, different spreads, etc) -- and any distribution we nominate will probably be very unlike the one you have. As a result you should explain more about what you want to achieve and what other information is available about the variable.